# How to know whether task is failed in Task<T> API using when kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

Classic way of signing in a user to firebase in kotlin, using callbacks is:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener {
    if(it.isSuccessful) {
        Toast.maketext("Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val authResult = it.result
        // Do other stuff
    } else {
        Toast.maketext("Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // Handle failure
    }
}
```

Using play service kotlin couroutines, this can be simplified as:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        val authResult = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential).await()
        Toast.maketext("Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // Do other stuff
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

Now I'm confused, where to handle failure. I could have done that in catch block, but catch block catches all exceptions. So how do I know which exception is caused by task being unsuccessful.

[This](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html) documentation does not mention any of these cases and I'm unable to find any source which explains this part in detail.

Comment: In the same place, in the catch. If your are waiting the result and while is processing the result is an exception, then you can handle it in the catch. If you are using some architecture you could to return a Result wrapper (is a sealed class with Success and Error state) and that´s all.

Comment: @ManuelMato Catch blocks catches all kinds of exception. But I want whether `task.isSuccessful` is false (which is not an exception at all). See above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [signInWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)).  It can yield three different types of exceptions, but they are all subclasses of [FirebaseAuthException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException).

You can either:

1. Narrow the type of exception(s) being caught, so that it only captures the ones you expect.  You can capture them all like this:

```
try {
    // do sign in
}
catch (e: FirebaseAuthException) {
}
```

Or you can capture them individually:

```
try {
    // do sign in
}
catch (e: FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) {
}
catch (e: FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
}
catch (e: FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
}
```

2. Or, you can discriminate within a catch for all exceptions, and decide what you want to do:

```
try {
    // do sign in
}
catch (e: Exception) {
    if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
        // handle auth exceptions
    }
    else {
        // handle other exceptions
    }
}
```